Is uttering of Testimony a condition to enter Islam?
The common practice seen or heard of people entering Islam is by uttering the twin declarations.
Since a deaf or mute person who wants to enter Islam cannot say these testimonies, I was trying to understand if any other ways are valid to enter Islam.
After much deliberations with academicians and sincere muslims, people suggested to contact a scholar.
Further a report in bukhari numbered 391 suggests there are other tacit ways of following Islam.

Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Whoever prays like us and faces our Qibla and eats our slaughtered animals is a Muslim and is under Allah's and His Apostle's protection. So do not betray Allah by betraying those who are in His protection."

Additionally the report 50 of bukhari suggests there is no condition of uttering the testimony.

What is Islam?" Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) replied, "To worship Allah Alone and none else, to offer prayers perfectly to pay the compulsory charity (Zakat) and to observe fasts during the month of Ramadan

Hence my question is uttering the testimony a condition to become a Muslim.
